# Is there any chance to get current time(every second) without updating the state in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, time

Please advise how to get current time for every second without state as it renders the components every time the state is updated. Please check the below code done using state

```
export default class Local extends React.Component {
state = {
messages: [],
currentTime: Date.now()
}


updateCurrentTime() {
setInterval(() => {
  this.setState({
    currentTime : new Date().getSeconds()
  })
}, 1000)
}

componentDidMount() {
this.updateCurrentTime();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have the component not rerender if you are updating the state variable. What you can do is limit how big the component that's being updated. So create a child component that just display your timer. When the timer updates, only the child component will get rerendered.

```
                              parent component
                                  /\
                                 /  \
                                /    \
                             COMP1   Timer
```

Updating the state variable in the Timer component won't cause rerender in the parent and COMP1 components.